# How do i place a wall in minecraft with properties

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was thinking that:

```
/setblock ~ ~ ~ minecraft:andesite_wall[east=low,west=low,north=low,south=low,up=false,waterlogged=false]
```

but it does not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your block is updating when placed, which causes it to rescan the surroundings and unset your blockstates. You can re-add them using the Debug Stick, which does not cause an update.

Comment: Thanks, i was thinking it woud work, because it worked with other blocks like redstone lamp.